# Markdown: How to create ordered lists?

Tags: markdown

I want to create a simple ordered list in Markdown, just as the `<ul><li></li></ul>` in HTML but I find now way to do so anywhere I tried to read about it.

I tried for example:

```
- firstNum
- secondNum

+ firstNum
+ secondNum
```

I hoped to get `1`, and `2`, but sadly didn't get this in the GitHub preview.

Is there really no way to create simple ordered lists in Markdown? Must I use HTML (which I don't want)? Any idea on this?

Comment: This is trivial to find with a web search. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, I didn't invent to try what I tried. I quote the comment I made to the answer: `I think I either missed the manual or that particular explanation in this hard period of many stress. I thank you for quoting this from the man`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer to this question can easily be found in the official [Markdown documentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list):

> Ordered lists use numbers followed by periods:
>
> ```
> 1.  Bird
> 2.  McHale
> 3.  Parish
> ```
>
> It’s important to note that the actual numbers you use to mark the
>   list have no effect on the HTML output Markdown produces. The HTML
>   Markdown produces from the above list is:
>
> ```
> <ol>
> <li>Bird</li>
> <li>McHale</li>
> <li>Parish</li>
> </ol>
> ```
>
> If you instead wrote the list in Markdown like this:
>
> ```
> 1.  Bird
> 1.  McHale
> 1.  Parish
> ```
>
> or even:
>
> ```
> 3. Bird
> 1. McHale
> 8. Parish
> ```
>
> you’d get the exact same HTML output. The point is, if you want to,
>   you can use ordinal numbers in your ordered Markdown lists, so that
>   the numbers in your source match the numbers in your published HTML.
>   But if you want to be lazy, you don’t have to.
>
> If you do use lazy list numbering, however, you should still start the
>   list with the number 1. At some point in the future, Markdown may
>   support starting ordered lists at an arbitrary number.

Comment: I think I either missed the manual or that particular explanation in this hard period of many stress. I thank you for quoting this from the man.

Comment: Markdown is not an adept system to switch between numeric symbols. For example, if you wanted to switch to arabic numbers, other markup can do it but markdown can not.